# Ember components in subdirectory

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've read that having directories/folders inside of /components is now supported. Using ember-cli I can generate the necessary subdirectory/component required. However, I cannot seem to reference the component.

For example if I a folder structure like this:

```
app/components/sub/test-comp.js
app/templates/components/sub/test-comp.hbs
```

referencing by: (in another .hbs file)

```
{{test-comp model=model}}
```

gives me the following error:

```
A helper named 'test-comp' could not be found
```

ember: 1.10.0

ember-cli: 0.2.0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the full path to the component:

```
{{sub/test-comp model=model}}
```

---

EDIT: In reference to the issue Leo is having, it turns out it's a generator problem. The component generator creates something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/sub/foo-bar';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout: layout
});
```

As far as I'm aware, there's no reason to import the layout like that. Unless something big has changed, component layouts are discovered automatically (if you're using the default naming conventions). I don't know why it does this (could be a bug), but you can fix it by removing the import like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

});
```

---

EDIT 2: It looks like [this is a known issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3514). I still don't know why importing the layout manually is necessary, as the component should work just fine without it.

Comment: I did try that and the error is slightly different: 
Could not find module `myApp/components/templates/components/sub/test-comp`

Comment: That is an odd path. Is that the exact error you get? There's no reason it should be looking for a `templates` folder inside of your `components` folder.

Comment: Also, which versions of Ember and Ember-CLI are you using?

Comment: That's the error it gives. I'm on ember-cli 0.2.0 and ember 1.10.0

Comment: I updated my answer. Turns out that the slash is correct, you just had an incorrect component generated.

Comment: Nice. I did notice that layout was coming in with new generator, but just assumed that it was required.