# How to add templates to sub-directories in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am quite sure the answer to my question is somewhere in some docs, I read many pages, on official and unofficial websites, many related questions on SO, but my google-fu seems not developed enough to help me find the answer, so here I am.

In my team we are using Ember-cli for some web application. We have the classic app/templates folder in which we put the .hbs of each "controller" we have. In those handlebars templates, we use components which are in app/templates/components.

We recently have reached a point where the app/templates/components is too big. I thought that it would be good idea to split them into sub-directories, e.g.

- app/templates/product1 containing specific-to-product1 components + the base product1 handlebar (the one called in app/router.js, a "controler's hbs").
- app/templates/product2 containing specific-to-product2 components + the base product2 handlebar (the one called in app/router.js, a "controler's hbs").

But when I do that, it doesn't work and displays a white page:

- If I move the "controler's hbs" from app/templates to app/templates/product1, I have a whole white page with nothing loaded.
- If I move a component from app/templates/components to app/templates/product1, the "controler's hbs" shows, but I have an empty block where my component is supposed to be.

I don't know if I have to configure ember for it to recursively search for handlebars in the app/templates folder, and/or if I have to change the router.js, and how to call my components so ember knows where they are.

Thanks in advance,

Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

Override the `templateName` property.

```
App.YourStuffComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    templateName: 'components/intoDir/your-stuff'
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jenafa/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I created a folder product-a in app/components, and put my js inside:
`app/components/product-a/some-component.js`. I did the same for my template: 
`app/templates/components/product-a/some-component.hbs`

Finally in app.js I added: 
`App.SomeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({ templateName: 'components/product-a/SomeComponent'});` but it didn't work. I also tried: 
`App.SomeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({ templateName: 'components/product-a/some-component.hbs'});` same error: white page and Assertion failed: a helper named 'some-component' could not be found.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Components in subfolder should work fine. Try a folder name without a slash.  Also you need Ember 1.9.0+. What version are you using? See rwjblue's comment: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2570

Comment: Also, if that is what you really want, then your question was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038704/ember-components-in-subdirectory

Comment: Hello again ! Sorry for this late answer, I was focusing on other things. The link you gave me is exactly what I needed, my question was already asked...

Thank you for you help and your link, it works perfectly now !